# Tag [ngx-graphs] should be retagged as [ngx-graph]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I suggest to rename [ngx-graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngx-graphs) by [ngx-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngx-graph) according to its library name

[NGX-GRAPH](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph).

Comment: ...or synonomize them.

Comment: I can't synonomize it : I don't have enough score on it.

Comment: No but mods can I think....not that [tag:ngx-graph] exists yet

Comment: Yeah, someone has just created it. :)